# I can't get my button to respond to a function

Tags: javascript

Here's the code that I'm using.

```
<script>
function login(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

if(username == "Ethan" && password == "Horton"){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Logged In: "Ethan"
}
else{
    alert("Incorrect User/Pass")
    }
}
</script>
<br />


Username: <input type="text" name="username" id = "username">

Password: <input type="password" name="password" id = "password">

<button type = "button" onclick = "login()">Login</button>
```

When I press the button, the function isn't called. (I'm kind of new to JavaScript.)

Comment: (1) jQuery would make this pretty easy. (2) It looks like you're attempting to authenticate using purely JS - this is a bad idea.

Comment: Looks like there are a couple of syntax errors in your Javascript. Have you checked your JS error console?

Comment: It is a test run of a straight-forward login system for a non-public login system- I just want to mess around with it.

Comment: hit f12 in your browser and check the console for JS errors.

Comment: The answer by Eugene was great. It works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this string: `"Logged In: "Ethan"`. It's incorrect.

You can wrap it in single quotes or escape regular qouotes:

```
'Logged In: "Ethan"'

"Logged In: \"Ethan\""
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/LDLN4/

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is wrap the response in quotes.

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Logged In: "Ethan" //incorrect

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Logged In: Ethan" //CORRECT
```

since you are just displaying a string the entire thing needs to be wrapped in quotes. If you stored that string in a variable you would not need the quotes

```
var loggedInMessage = "Logged In: Ethan";
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = loggedInMessage;
```

So remember, quotes mean a string and no quotes means you are calling on a variable. (If the variable has been defined and you try to call it you will get an error)